# Analogies from Word2Vec in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, word-embedding

I implemented Word Embeddings in Tensor Flow similarly to the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) I was able to get the final embeddings (final_embeddings), but I would like to evaluate the embeddings using the analogies typical of this exercise. How can I identify which term corresponds to which row in the final embeddings array? Alternatively, is there an implementation in Tensor Flow for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated (specifics and resources would be a plus;) ). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend this [conceptual tutorial](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) to you. 
If you are using skip-gram, the input is one-hot encoding. So the index of the `1` is the index of the vector of the word.

[image]

The implementation in tensorflow is quite simple. You may want to see this function: [tf.nn.embedding_lookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup)

For example:

```
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs)
```

The embed is the vector you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Qy Zuo! That's what I thought. When I implement the analogies, the results I get are non-sensical, and now I'm not certain why! Is it possible that the function of the embeddings (in this capacity) is highly variable with the dimension of the embedding? Note, that I have arbitrarily chosen a dimension, as I was just running a preliminary exercise.

Comment: @user3009734 Yes, you're right. The dimension can vary from 20 to 1000. You can choose this hyper param according to your vocab size but it does not has strict mappings. Socher explained this perfectly in this course (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRqn8t1hLxs) and it really made things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Which term corresponds to which row in the final embeddings array is completely up to your implementation. At some point before your training you converted each word to a number, right? This number indicates that row in your embeddings table.

If you want to know the specific name, you could post part of your code here.